# Is the yellow Sun light produced by photon scattering inside the Sun?

Tags: visible-light, temperature, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, sun

If the hydrogen emits four distinct light frequencies as a gas and on the Sun surface the gravity cannot alter hydrogen state as a gas does the yellow component of sunlight come from its interior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuum light seen from the photosphere of the Sun is due to interactions between electrons and hydrogen atoms producing H$^{-}$ ions. The formation of these ions produces a recombination continuum. The breaking up of these ions is a major source of opacity in the photosphere. The H atoms are of course plentiful. The free electrons are supplied by easily ionised elements, particularly sodium and potassium.

There are of course other sources of opacity and emission in the photosphere, mostly at narrow ranges of frequencies around prominent Fraunhofer lines due to hydrogen (Balmer lines) and metallic atoms such as calcium, magnesium and sodium, and a host of weaker lines due to iron and other iron-peak elements.

However, the overwhelming reasons for the Sun's pseudo-blackbody spectrum is the H$^{-}$ ion.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the light from the Sun is broad-spectrum *[black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)* from the Sun's *[photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere)*. Hydrogen (and other elements) in the photosphere are detected mainly by *[absorption spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_spectroscopy)* rather than by *[emission spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_spectrum)*.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the spectrum is a consequence of inelastic scattering of photons.

The atoms and ions in the Sun's atmosphere are hot, and have a broad distribution of kinetic energy. Photons scatter from them, some gaining energy, some losing energy.  Clearly the average kinetic energy of the atoms/ions is not increasing with time nor decreasing with time.  A steady state has been reached where *on the whole* photons loose as much energy as they gain.  This is an equilibrium situation, and the spectral distribution of the photons is universal, depending only on the temperature, and is continuous.  The distribution is called the *blackbody spectrum*.

Well, all of that is not *exactly* correct, as the atoms can absorb light as well as scatter it, so those distinct frequencies cause certain frequencies to have less intensity than expected.  They show up in spectra as dips in the spectral intensity distribution.